# Sort issue with delimiter in excel

Tags: excel, sorting, delimiter

I have a column of data in excel that contains cells of just numbers and then cells of two numbers with a delimiter in between. I want to sort by this field but when I do so it puts all the fields with delimiters down at the bottom. I would like them to be sorted by the first number thats before the delimiter.  Would there be an easy to do this using sort or another built in feature?

Regular Cell:

123456

Delimited Cell:

123456 | 789012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add one additional column and then split delimited cells and sort the new column.

This would be the easiest i guess

Comment: Is there a way to sort by the first 3 numbers?

Comment: do `texttocolumn` and convert the column into text and then sort
I think it should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Rather than one, big function, let me show you how to split out the first number before the delimiter.

Let's say A1 is `123456 | 789012`.

In B1, put the formula `=FIND("|",A1)`. This will be the index of the delimiter, 8, or a #VALUE error if no delimiter is found.

In C1, put the formula `=ISERROR(B1)`. This returns a TRUE if it finds the delimiter, or else a FALSE.

In D1, put the formula `=IF(NOT(C1),LEFT(A1,B1-1),"")`. This returns the string before the delimiter, 123456, including a trailing blank. You may sort on this as a string, if all the numbers have the same number of digits. (Note that string 21 is lexically higher than string 123456.)

If you need to sort the numbers a numbers, then in E1, put the formula `=VALUE(D1)`. Now 21 < 123456.